# Data Structure for One Entry with Unknown Number of Tags

Tags: sql, database, csv

Noob here.  I am trying to create a class or data structure where each entry has one unique name and an unknown number of descriptive tags.  I'd like the data structure to be something I could also easily export to some common format (I am guessing that CSV would not be able to do what I am asking since I think I need multiple delimiters somehow?).

For background, I am trying to define this data structure so that later I can implement a way to pull up each entry and see all the tags as well as be able to implement a way to search to see which entries contain a particular tag.

Here's an example of the raw data I would be looking at which has one unique name, one non-unique number, and an unknown number of non-unique tags.

```
Name: Jim
Age: 47
Descriptors (Tags): Fat, Tall, Wrinkly

Name: Bob
Age: 88
Descriptors: Sad

Name: Charlie
Age: 12
Descriptor: Tall, Ugly
```

Comment: Since you tagged SQL, I'm assuming you want to use a relational database.  You'd create a Person table with the name and age, and a Descriptor table pointing back to the Person row, one row for each descriptor.  Jim would have three Descriptor rows, and Bob would have one Descriptor row.  The Wikipedia article, [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) will provide more details.

Comment: Thanks Gilbert! To clarify, when you say Jim would have 3 descriptor rows, do you mean that the data in Descriptor Table in SQL would have a row for each descriptor and the people's names would be in columns?  So that if two people had the same descriptor then they would be in the same row for that descriptor?  Or alternatively are you saying each row consists of exactly one name and one descriptor? I added a 3rd person to my example to illustrate.

Comment: Hmm I wasn't aware that there are things like the CONTAINS command. So maybe the Tags are text then maybe they could just be all dumped into one cell and searched for with the CONTAINS command in a SQL environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would design the tables.

```
Person Table

Person ID   Name       Birthdate
----------------------------------
        1   Jim       1973-10-02
        2   Bob       1932-06-02
        3   Charlie   2008-12-25


Descriptor Table

Descriptor ID   Person ID   Tag
--------------------------
            1           1   Fat
            2           1   Tall
            3           1   Wrinkly
            4           2   Sad
            5           3   Tall
            6           3   Ugly
```

The ID fields of both tables are an auto-incrementing integer.  They are also called blind keys.  They have no meaning other than to connect tables together.

The ID fields of both tables are the primary (clustering) key.  The Person ID in the Descriptor Table is a foreign key pointing back to the Person Table.

The name and birth date appear once for each person.

When you want to retrieve the tags from the Descriptor table, you need to specify the Person ID.  You can do this indirectly, by using the name or birth date.

```
SELECT Tag FROM Descriptor Table, Person Table
WHERE Person ID Descriptor = Person ID Person
AND Name = 'Bob'
```

The above is not valid SQL, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Much thanks!  I googled "blind keys" related to SQL to no avail, but is it correct to say that I could do without the Descriptor ID column or was there a reason for it's existence?  I see you mention blind keys being used to join tables (and get how that's critical in the Person table) but not sure how I could use the Descriptor ID to join anything, but I suppose maybe for other situations then maybe it's applicable.  Is that correct?

Comment: I put blind keys on every table, even if they're not used currently.  Every table needs a primary key, and a blind primary key is short and unique.

Answer (score 1):

In a database, you would typically do this with at least two tables:

- `Users`
- `UserTags`

The second table would have one row per user and per tag.  Inserting a new tag is inserting a row in this table:

```
userId  tag
  1     tall
  1     ugly
```

If the tags must come from a specified list, then there would typically be a third table, `Tags` to ensure that the tags are valid.

Some databases support structures with multiple values in a row.  An array or JSON array is a possible solution as well.  However, I would start with the standard normalized representation in a database.

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify what you mean by "the second table would have one row per user and per tag?  Do you mean that each row would contain exactly one descriptor and exactly one name (ie two cells)?  Or alternatively are you saying that each row would contain one unique descriptor and an unknown number of names?  Thanks!

Comment: @rfii . . . Okay.  I guess this wasn't clear enough for you.

Comment: The update cleared it up! I appreciate you explaining everything for us noobs